# Non-sensical Error: Misplaced argument matcher detected here. You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing in Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I have multiple Spock Test Suites in my code. When I try to execute them serially, I am getting the following error message on running Spock Tests:

```
 Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
    [junit] 
    [junit] -> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    [junit] 
    [junit] You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
    [junit] Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    [junit]     when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    [junit]     doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    [junit]     verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
    [junit] 
    [junit] This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
    [junit] like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
    [junit] use primitive alternatives.
    [junit]     when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    [junit]     when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use
    [junit] 
    [junit] Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
    [junit] Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
    [junit] Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
    [junit] 
    [junit] org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
    [junit] Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
    [junit] 
    [junit] -> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    [junit] 
    [junit] You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
    [junit] Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    [junit]     when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    [junit]     doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    [junit]     verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
    [junit] 
    [junit] This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
    [junit] like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
    [junit] use primitive alternatives.
    [junit]     when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    [junit]     when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use
    [junit] 
    [junit] Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
    [junit] Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
    [junit] Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
    [junit] 
    [junit]     at com.example.app.MySecondTest.test update usages(MySecondTest.groovy:19)
    [junit]
```

However, the error points to `MySecondTest.groovy:19` which in my case contains the following code

`ExampleService exampleService = Mockito.mock(ExampleService.class)`

There is no use of Argument Matcher in `MySecondTest`. But still I am getting this error.

Curiously, if I run only this test, I do not get any error and the test runs successfully

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the error message points to next TestSuite that is executed after the test that actually contains a misplaced Argument Matcher.

In my case, the test suite `MyFirstTest`, which was executed before the test suite `MySecondTest` contained a test method that had a misplaced Argument Matcher.